# Add <tr> after <tr>

Tags: jquery, html-table

I wanted to add new row using jQuery.

Like this:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>einlanzer</td>
        <td>dev</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="addme" value="add">
```

How can I add new table row or grid using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

`insertAfter`: This will insert the element after the specified element.

```
$('<tr />').insertAfter('table tr:last');
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

`append`: Will append to the end of the element.

```
$('table').append('<tr></tr>');
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Mind explain a little bit ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#addme').click(function() {
  $('table').append('<tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>desc</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>description</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>einlanzer</td>
    <td>dev</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" id="addme" value="add me please">
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.append()` to add the new row after last row:

```
$('table').append('Markup_for_tr');
```

if you want to append after certain tr(say after first tr):

```
$('table tr:eq(0)').after("Markup_for_tr");
```